# multithreading java and neural network : reading 2 csv files at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, encog

I'm working with a neural network project that requires to run two instance of the neural network program with different training set speciffically two at the same time. For that I'am using mutithreading in java plus encog library for the implementation of the ANN.  So I created two threads each of them contains the ANN implementation but with two different CSV files. I have part of the result works wich returns the min and max for every comlumn in the CSV files but the problem that the output of the ANN is computed for just one files. Here is my implementation:

ReadfileMT.java

```
    public class ReadFileMT implements Runnable {


    public static void dumpFieldInfo(EncogAnalyst analyst) {

     System.out.println("Fields found in file:");
    for (AnalystField field : analyst.getScript().getNormalize()
            .getNormalizedFields())
          {

        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        line.append(field.getName());
        line.append(",action=");
        line.append(field.getAction());
        line.append(",min=");
        line.append(field.getActualLow());
        line.append(",max=");
        line.append(field.getActualHigh());
        System.out.println(line.toString());
    }
}

     public void run() {
     File sourceFile = new File("d:\\data\\F21.csv");
                    File targetFile = new File("d:\\data\\F2_norm.csv"); 
        EncogAnalyst analyst = new EncogAnalyst();
                AnalystWizard wizard = new AnalystWizard(analyst);
                    AnalystField targetField = wizard.getTargetField();
                    wizard.setTargetField("Old_Resp");
        wizard.wizard(sourceFile, true, AnalystFileFormat.DECPNT_COMMA);
        dumpFieldInfo(analyst);
        final AnalystNormalizeCSV norm = new AnalystNormalizeCSV();
        norm.analyze(sourceFile, true, CSVFormat.ENGLISH, analyst);
                    norm.setProduceOutputHeaders(true);
                    norm.normalize(targetFile);
                   // Encog.getInstance().shutdown();
        //*****************************Read from the csv file**************************************************               



    final BasicNetwork network = EncogUtility.simpleFeedForward(4,  4, 0, 1,
                            false);

     network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new     ActivationSigmoid(),false,4));
     network.addLayer(newBasicLayer(newActivationSigmoid(),false,4));
     network.addLayer(newBasicLayer(newActivationSigmoid(),false,1));
     network.getStructure().finalizeStructure();
     network.reset();
            //create training data
            final MLDataSet trainingSet = TrainingSetUtil.loadCSVTOMemory(
            CSVFormat.ENGLISH, "c:\\temp\\F2_norm.csv",false, 4, 1);

            // train the neural network
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Training Network");
     final   Backpropagationtrain=newBackpropagation
     (network,trainingSet,0.05,0.9);
            train.fixFlatSpot(false);
            int epoch = 1;

    do {
        train.iteration();
        System.out.println("Epoch #" + epoch + " Error:" +train.getError());
        epoch++;
    } while(train.getError() > 0.01);
    train.finishTraining();
           //final Train train=newResilientPropagation(network,trainingSet);
           /*int epoch = 1;
        do {
            train.iteration();
            System.out.println("Epoch #" + epoch + " Error:"
                    + train.getError() * 100 + "%");
            epoch++;
        } while (train.getError() > 0.015);*/

            /*int epoch = 1;

    do {
        train.iteration();
        System.out.println("Epoch #" + epoch + " Error:" +train.getError());
        epoch++;
    } while(train.getError() > 0.01);
    train.finishTraining();*/




            // test the neural network


            System.out.println("Neural Network Results:");
    for(MLDataPair pair: trainingSet ) {
        final MLData output = network.compute(pair.getInput());
         System.out.println(pair.getInput().getData(0)+",
         "+pair.getInput().getData(1)+","+ pair.getInput().getData(2)
         +","+   pair.getInput().getData(3) 
         + ", actual=" + output.getData(0) + ",ideal="
        +pair.getIdeal().getData(0));
    }

    Encog.getInstance().shutdown();

}
        }
```

ReadFileMT2.java

```
    public class ReadFileMT2 implements Runnable {


    public static void dumpFieldInfo(EncogAnalyst analyst) {

     System.out.println("Fields found in file:");
    for (AnalystField field : analyst.getScript().getNormalize()
            .getNormalizedFields())
          {

        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        line.append(field.getName());
        line.append(",action=");
        line.append(field.getAction());
        line.append(",min=");
        line.append(field.getActualLow());
        line.append(",max=");
        line.append(field.getActualHigh());
        System.out.println(line.toString());
     }
    }


     public void run() {
     File sourceFile = new File("d:\\data\\RespTime.csv");
     File targetFile =newFile("d:\\data\\RespTime_norm.csv"); 
        EncogAnalyst analyst = new EncogAnalyst();
                AnalystWizard wizard = new AnalystWizard(analyst);
                    AnalystField targetField = wizard.getTargetField();
                    wizard.setTargetField("Old_Resp");
        wizard.wizard(sourceFile, true, AnalystFileFormat.DECPNT_COMMA);
        dumpFieldInfo(analyst);
        final AnalystNormalizeCSV norm = new AnalystNormalizeCSV();
        norm.analyze(sourceFile, true, CSVFormat.ENGLISH, analyst);
                    norm.setProduceOutputHeaders(true);
                    norm.normalize(targetFile);
                   // Encog.getInstance().shutdown();
        //******Read from the csv file*************************              



    final BasicNetwork network = EncogUtility.simpleFeedForward(4, 4, 0, 1,
                            false);

            network.addLayer(newBasicLayer(newActivationSigmoid(),false,4));
            network.addLayer(newBasicLayer(newActivationSigmoid(),false,4));
            network.addLayer(newBasicLayer(newActivationSigmoid(),false,1));
            network.getStructure().finalizeStructure();
            network.reset();
            //create training data
            final MLDataSet trainingSet = TrainingSetUtil.loadCSVTOMemory(
            CSVFormat.ENGLISH, "c:\\temp\\RespTime_norm.csv",false, 4, 1);

            // train the neural network
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Training Network");

            final Backpropagation train = new Backpropagation
            (network,trainingSet,0.05, 0.9);
            train.fixFlatSpot(false);
            int epoch = 1;

    do {
        train.iteration();
        System.out.println("Epoch #" + epoch + " Error:" +train.getError());
        epoch++;
     } while(train.getError() > 0.01);
     train.finishTraining();

           /*int epoch = 1;
        do {
            train.iteration();
            System.out.println("Epoch #" + epoch + " Error:"
                    + train.getError() * 100 + "%");
            epoch++;
        } while (train.getError() > 0.015);*/

            /*int epoch = 1;

    do {
        train.iteration();
        System.out.println("Epoch #" + epoch + " Error:" +train.getError());
        epoch++;
    } while(train.getError() > 0.01);
    train.finishTraining();*/




            // test the neural network


            System.out.println("Neural Network Results:");
    for(MLDataPair pair: trainingSet ) {
        final MLData output = network.compute(pair.getInput());
        System.out.println(pair.getInput().getData(0) + ","
        +pair.getInput().getData(1)+",
        "+ pair.getInput().getData(2)+
        ","+ pair.getInput().getData(3) 
        + ", actual=" +output.getData(0)+",ideal="+
        pair.getIdeal().getData(0));
    }

    Encog.getInstance().shutdown();

      }
        }
```

main.java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       ReadFileMT obj1 = new ReadFileMT();
       ReadFileMT2 obj2 = new ReadFileMT2();
       Thread t1 = new Thread(obj1);
       Thread t2 = new Thread(obj2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

             }
      }
```

I don't understand what is wrong. Ps : Iam new in parralel programming

Comment: please, add what exactly you want to achieve: do you want to split results in different files or to write them in one (in particular order)

Comment: Iam using neural network for prediction time series so i have two CSV  with different data i want the ANN to give me the prediction of the two csv files in parralel no spliting files they are alearedy splited to sum up i want two instance of the same ANN that runs in parralel each of them take a csv file to do prediction

Comment: Pleaze tell me i can't achieve what i want?

Comment: someone helps me pleaze pleaze

Comment: Did you try to run each method separately? Does each method  works correctly?

Comment: Seperatly , just one method works which is ReadFileMT2.java .the other don't work  however it contains the same implementation just a different csv file

Comment: So, the problem is not in parallel execution. Is the file ReadFileMT2 compile? Try to rewrite you ReadFileMT class to pass input/output fileNames to it. So you will use the same code

Comment: Yes ReadFileMT2  compile , know i have the two files  ReadFileMT2  and ReadFileMT with the same implementation and the same file always the same error the parrel prediction that should neural network compute not working. it compute just one i mean that normally i should get 2 times the same result